# MySQL convert columns to rows

Tags: mysql, database, join, pivot-table, union

I have a query which is formed by joining of two select statements which returns result as column A,B,C,A,B,C. Here A,B,C is the name of the column which is same but values is different as it is result set from two different queries. Now I want to have two rows for A,B,C instead of displaying data in one row for both the tables. like this :-

Present :-

```
         A   B  C   A   B   C
Values  X1  X2 x3  Y1  Y2  Y3
```

Required :-

```
                     A   B  C
Value from table 1  X1  X2 x3
Value from Table 2  Y1  Y2 Y3
```

Now my condition is I want alternative results i.e. one row from Table1 and then one row from Table2, then again row from table1 and table2 so on ......

Here is some sample code.

```
Select * from 
        ( Select x,y,z from table1 ) A 
   join ( Select x,y,z from table1 ) B on A.x = B.x and A.y = B.z and A.z = B.y
```

Comment: where is your query

Comment: You want to use UNION ALL instead of join

Comment: @denny - its possible , check the sample code.

Select *   
from  
(  
  Select x,y,z  
  from table1  
) A  
join   
(  
  Select x,y,z  
  from table1  
) B on A.x = B.x and A.y = B.z and A.z = B.y

The code will return x,y,z column from Query A and then x,y,z Column from Query B

Comment: ok misundestanding

Comment: @GurV - No Union All will not serve my purpose as i want to use where clause for Table 2 based on the values from Table 1 and as far my understanding , we cannot use where clause after Union. If I'am going somewhere wrong, Please suggest.

Comment: @NavnitMishra - Hi , What exactly you want to understand from query , Please share so that i can provide you useful inputs accordingly.

Comment: @denny - No problem. So now can you suggest any solution ?

Comment: It's always best when adding sample code to [edit] the question rather than burying the sample code in a comment.

Comment: @O.Jones - Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL`, your intuition to the contrary notwithstanding.

Probably part of your problem derives from the confused names of columns due to  your use of `SELECT *`. Pro tip: Avoid `SELECT *`.

Given the sample you provided in a comment, you can get what you want like this.

```
Select A.x, A.y, A.z
  from ( Select x,y,z from table1 ) A 
  join ( Select x,y,z from table1 ) B on A.x = B.x and A.y = B.z and A.z = B.y 
 UNION ALL
Select B.x, B.y, B.z
  from ( Select x,y,z from table1 ) A 
  join ( Select x,y,z from table1 ) B on A.x = B.x and A.y = B.z and A.z = B.y
```

You do it like this:

```
 SELECT a1 a, b1 b, c1 c FROM t
  UNION ALL
 SELECT a2 a, b2 b, c2 c FROM t
```

`t` is defined as a complex structured query.  That's going to make your life a little complex, because *you will be repeating that query twice* to get the result you want?  Why? MySQL doesn't have common table expressions.

You may want to define `t` as a view to save yourself some typing. Or you may want to use temporary tables, especially if the query generating `t` is time-consuming.

Comment: thanks for the edits in Question . Now my doubt is If I use Union All , will I be able to get final result in alternate order ?? As I have mentioned in my initial question that I want 

A.x, A.y, A.z  
B.x, B.y, B.z  
A.x, A.y, A.z  
B.x, B.y, B.z  

If Yes , then how ?

Comment: There's *no such thing as default ordering* in SQL. Unless a query contains an `ORDER BY` clause the ordering of the result set is *formally unpredictable.*  That is computer science jargon for *if you rely on ordering without an `ORDER BY` clause, you will be sorry.*  You didn't explain how your original result set is supposed to be ordered.

Comment: Thanks for the clues. I have created Temp table for storing values in A & B then used UNION ALL to extract alternate records using rank feature.